# C++ why is my recursive function behaving differently when i fuse loops?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I am trying to count the number of 'steps' (each time i travel to a new node it is counted as a new step) needed to travel through a tree like structure with my recursive function.

The way I intend the function to work is to travel all the way down one path to the last call (i have a break, to signify the end) through recursion,go back to the previous call go onto the next step in a for loop to go to a different node ...

then go back to the for loop of the call before that after the for loop finishes ...

all the way back to the first node where it moves down another path. I'm sorry about the bad explanation.

Also I am not looking for a more efficient traversal algorithms I just need to know why this algorithm doesn't work after I tried fusing the 2 for loops, and what i can change to fix that.

```
void mario( int current_node, int current_depth ) {
    vector<int> luigi;
    vector<int> wario;
    for( int i = 0; i <= vec[current_node]; i++ ) {

        if( i >= current_node ) {
            if( current_depth != 0 ) {

                luigi.push_back(current_depth - 1);//store new depth
                wario.push_back(i + 1);            //store new_node

            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {

            luigi.push_back(current_depth);        //depth stays the same
            wario.push_back(i);                    //store new_node

        }


        }
    for(int r=0; r < luigi.size();r++){

        counter += 1;
        mario(wario[r],luigi[r]);                  //call the function

    }

}
```

the only differences between this one and the next are that I store the new_node and new_depth in vectors and then call the function in a new loop, to me that seemed like an extra step.

```
void mario( int current_node, int current_depth ) {
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)reduction(+:counter)
    for( int i = 0; i <= vec[current_node]; i++ ) {

        if( i >= current_node ) {
            if( current_depth != 0 ) {
                new_depth = current_depth - 1;
                new_node = i + 1;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            new_depth = current_depth;
            new_node = i; 
        }

        counter+=1;
        mario( new_node, new_depth );
    }  
}
/* why does this behave differently?,or is it the actually equivalent but the problem is elsewhere?*/
```

with the for loops fused and the vector gone the new function travels all the way down one path to the last call, goes back to the previous call finishes the for loop and then just ends with out going back to the call before that and so on...

What other unintended changes have I made in the new function and how can i negate them? I am new to C++ and I want to try and learn.

I apologise for my badly worded question, if it feels unclear please suggest improvements I can make to this question to make answering easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to implement [depth-first traversal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

One difference between the two code samples is that the second one accesses global variables `new_depth` and `new_node` in the loop and as far as I understand, the line below is an OpenMP directive for parallelisation of the loop.

`#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)reduction(+:counter)`

This means that you are accessing shared memory concurrently without any synchronization, which is undefined behavior ([data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model))

Comment: thanks declaring new_node and new_depth as a local variable seems to have solved my problem.